# Using an older version of DatePicker in all the OS versions

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

I want to use the `DatePicker` of older version in all the android versions.

The old version of date picker looks like [image: this]

I want this type of date picker in all versions of android.

Is it possible to do such things....

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**:

please check above [library](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) it is good as per your requirement

you can do like this :

```
RadialTimePickerDialogFragment rtpd = new RadialTimePickerDialogFragment()
                .setOnTimeSetListener(SampleRadialTimeBasicUsage.this)
                .setStartTime(10, 10)
                .setDoneText("Yay")
                .setCancelText("Nop")
                .setThemeDark(true);
        rtpd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAG_TAG_TIME_PICKER);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... But the library is deprecated @Mr. Ad